# How do I connect another computer with only an ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet

I would like to connect another computer to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop and share its internet connection.  How do I do set this up?

Comment: This is a general Linux network question.  Not Raspberry Pi specific.